# Why are Map and Set aliased in scala.Predef?

Tags: scala

9 times out of 10, simply using `Map` and `Set` behave like I expect they would, but occasionally I am unexpectedly hit with

```
error: type mismatch; 
[INFO]  found   : scala.collection.Set[String]
[INFO]  required: Set[String]
```

As an example, from the REPL:

```
scala> case class Calculator[+T](name: String, parameters: Set[String])
defined class Calculator

scala> val binding=Map.empty[String, String]
binding: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map()

scala> Calculator("Hello",binding.keySet)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.Set[String]
required: Set[String]
       Calculator("Hello",binding.keySet)
                                  ^
```

I think I understand the error, that is, the function call on the aliased types return the actual types.

And so it seems to me the solution is to import the un-aliased types.  Upon which every other file in my project will now generate type mismatch errors, so I will have to import it in each file.  Which leads to the question I ask in the title -- what was the purpose of the alias in Predef, if eventually I need to import the actual package anyway?

Is my understanding flawed, or is my use case not the typical one, or both?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have misdiagnosed the problem.  It isn't that it doesn't recognize the type alias is the same type as what it is aliasing.  It's that the type alias is scala.collection.immutable.Set and that is not the same as scala.collection.Set.

Edit: by the way, I thought I'd fixed this, as evinced by the comment in the type diagnostics:

```
   ... Also, if the
*  type error is because of a conflict between two identically named
*  classes and one is in package scala, fully qualify the name so one
*  need not deduce why "java.util.Iterator" and "Iterator" don't match.
```

Apparently needs more work.

Edit 7/17/2010: OK, it took me a shockingly long time, but now at least it says something hard to misunderstand.

```
files/neg/type-diagnostics.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.Set[String]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
  def f = Calculator("Hello",binding.keySet)
                                     ^
```

Comment: Thanks -- That makes sense now that I look at it.  But I guess my question becomes 'How can I make this code do what I want with minimal cruft?'  If I need to cast/convert from one type to another as well as using fully qualified names for a use case as simple as the one above, I figure I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: You can always call .toSet on any collection to get an immutable set.  You may or may not be doing something wrong: this is mostly just what happens when you default to immutability but the whole world (including your own world) doesn't give you immutable things.

Comment: why immutable.Map#keySet doesn't returns an immutable.Set?

Comment: I don't know.  Because that's the way someone wrote it.  I tend to assume things are as they are for no particular reason until shown otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is that `scala.collection.immutable.Map#keySet` returns a `scala.collection.Set` (a read-only `Set`) instead of a `scala.collection.immutable.Set` (an immutable `Set`).  I'll leave it for someone else to explain why that is...

**Edit**

Someone asks for an explanation for the return type of `Map#keySet` in [this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/4900), but doesn't get an answer.